# "Короче говоря, я — не вещь, ничто"?

Tags: выбор-слов, цитата

> Кто я или что я? В своём **последнем основании**? Помимо званий, ролей, степеней и всех этих этикеток, наклеенных на меня? Помимо занятий и отношений, даже имени и личной истории? Кто я? Что я? Самый главный урок, которому меня научила жизнь, таков:
> сущность моего бытия состоит в субъективном осознании, представляющем
> собой непрерывный процесс. Окончательно я не могу отождествить себя ни
> с какой-либо материей (например, с моим телом), ни с чем-либо, что я
> произвожу (моими словами на этих страницах), ни с каким-либо из моих
> свойств (мой интерес к другим), ни с моим прошлым, ни с моими планами
> на будущее, ни с моими сиюминутными мыслями, ни с какой-либо иной
> вещью. **Короче говоря, я — не вещь, ничто.** Я — исключительно
> процесс моего бытия — например, процесс написания этих слов, — но я не
> содержание слов или идей, которые они выражают. Я — тот, кто осознаёт
> процесс письма, выбирает способы выражения суждений, надеется на
> понимание, **наслаждается возникновением мыслей и образов своих
> переживаний.**

"В своём последнем основании?" - что-то другое есть последнее, не основание...

Что было задумано под НИЧТО?

И вообще - что вас тут... шероховатит?

СПАСИБО.

Да! Всё это цитата, но, имхо, требующая малюсеньких корректив...

[Короче говоря, я - не вещь, ничто 5.](https://studfiles.net/preview/7511925/page:5/) - ПЯТЬ - это сноска. Я её не нашла! И если цитировать цитату без пояснений, можно слегка недоуметь. Как я.

---

УВИДИТЕ ОШИБКИ - КРИЧИТЕ!

---

Нашла!

> Короче говоря, я - не вещь, ничто5.
>
> 5 Игра слов: по-английски *no thing* (не вещь) и *nothing* (ничто) пишутся
> и произносятся почти одинаково. - *Прим. переводчика.*

И что делать при цитировании? Довольно дико внутрь собственного текста давать к цитате примечание переводчика; надо заменять слово...

КАК ЕЩЁ ПЕРЕВЕСТИ nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче говоря, я — **не вещь, не реальность, а ничто, отсутствие чего-либо.** Я — исключительно процесс моего бытия, **— например,** процесс написания этих слов, — но я не содержание слов или идей, которые они выражают. Я — тот, кто осознаёт процесс письма, выбирает способы выражения суждений, надеется на понимание, наслаждается возникновением мыслей и образов **для** своих переживаний.

Пояснение

1) **Перевод слова nothing:** https://wooordhunt.ru/word/nothing

— **отсутствие (чего-л.)**; пустота

— **небытие**, **нереальность;** полное исчезновение

2) **Запятая?** Относится к обособленному слову в начале вставки; или использовать симметричное оформление вставки. Так понятнее читается.

3) **Для своих переживаний:** родительный беспредложный повторяется, поэтому сложно прочитывается.

Comment: Спасибо, Шаронушка. Ворую идеи у себя - предлагаю обсудить: ***Я не вещь ни в малейшей степени. / Я нисколько не вещь. / Я — не вещь, не нечто*** - с учётом контекста. И даже так: ***Я — не вещь, не что*** - что нарисовать с ударением. Я ведь процесс...

Comment: Может быть так: я — не вещь, нисколько не вещь. А слово  "ничто" вообще убрать, nothing будет использоваться как усиление.

Comment: Проштудиров тему, я предложила автору вариант: "Я вообще ничто, меня нет". Это ближе всего к лепету параноика Лоренса. См.: http://www.psychotherapy.ruspsy.net/article.php?post=855

Comment: Параноик говорит, что он не материальный предмет, а процесс. Может быть, так: Я  не вещь, не что-то. Я — исключительно процесс моего бытия.  Здесь, как мне кажется. важно обозначить отрицание.

Answer (score 1):

Я - не вещь, я - ничто?

...в своих переживаниях?

Comment: Лёх, НЕ НИЧТО, имхо. Посмотрела список возможных переводов: наречие
совсем нет
nothing
ни в малейшей степени
not in the least, nothing
нисколько
any, not at all, nothing, none, not in the least, by no means
ВЫВОД (мой): я не вещь ни в малейшей степени. / я нисколько не вещь.

Comment: Так автор имел в виду именно этот английский каламбур?

Comment: Нет. Мой автор честно процитировал переводной текст. А в переводе - ето само "ничто". А я грю: НИЗЗЯ! Не это было задумано Джеймсом Бьюдженталем. Можно ль попробовать так: "Я — не вещь, не нечто!"?

Comment: Это же будет типа вольный перевод? Не знаю, тяжелый случай. )

Comment: Лучше вольный, чем бессмыслица.